# mod_rewrite issue with GET parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm modifying the Apache `.htaccess` file for rewrite products' URL, so I can go from this

```
domain.com/section/products/product.php?url=some-product-name
```

to this

```
domain.com/section/products/some-product-name
```

Here's the `mod_rewrite` code that I'm using:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^section/products/(.*)$ /section/products/product.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It just returns a 500 server error.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your rewrite rules are infinitely looping. Which is due to the fact `section/products/(.*)` pattern matches original and rewritten URI.

You can use this to fix it:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(section/products)/([\w-]+)$ $1/product.php?url=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: This is genius. Thank you very much. I need help with other `mod_rewrite` thing, and I can't make another question in 90 mins, can I ask for your help here in the comments?

Comment: Thanks. I have this folder called "products" in this path: `/section/products/`. I also have the _product echoer_ file (`products.php`), and I want to be able of differentiate between `products` and `products/`, so if the URL hasn't the slash should go to `products.php`. If the URL has the slash (without anything else passed as `get`) must redirect to `/section/products` (the .php file). I hope I explained that correctly.

Comment: Yes it is. Inside `/section/` I have `/section/products.php` and  `/section/products/`.

Comment: `products.php` is loaded from `/section/`, `product.php` is loaded from `/section/products/` and  `/section/products/` doesn't have a `index.php` file inside.

Comment: Is there any way to "simulate" the `/section/products`? Example, changing the name of the real folder to something like `the_products` and then re-direct it to `/section/products`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128965/discussion-between-anubhava-and-jimmy-adaro).